# How to release an AppIndicator reference created with app_indicator_new in a forked child?

Tags: c++, linux, appindicator

I have an App Indicator project that create a dynamically built launch menu.

The launch menu runs applications by fork/exec.  I need to destroy the app indicator in the forked child or somehow get it to release all it's handles/mutexes or whatever.  How do I close/release all these references from the forked child process?

The reason is that the menu sticks around after the parent AppIndicator process has exited.  There must be a way to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this did the trick:

```
AppIndicator * appind = app_indicator_new( /*params*/ )

// ... use appind

fork();
g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(appind)); // remove reference
execlp( /*params*/ );
```